# iframes not fitting in my div section holder correctly

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to fit 5 `iframes` in a `div`. I wanted two large `iframes` on top of each other and the 3 other smaller `iframes` to the right of the 2 large `iframes`.  The images on the `iframe` seem to overflow out of my div, it's not displaying inside the section holder.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkrpxyuq/1/) link to how it looks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/pkrpxyuq/2/)

Please have a look, may be that will do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you very much locateganesh. So all I had to do was create frames for the left and right side. I will remember that next time. Question though the *{ box-sizing:border-box;} i never seen you apply it to any of the html. Where did you use it as a id or a class?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @jason luong.. Wherever in html you use star(*). It means it applies to everywhere in DOM where it's a div, class, id, iframe, p, h1. All. So it's good to use box-sizing:border-box; to individuals class or id. It is recommended to apply all at once